# How to properly multicast result of HttpClient request to several components in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-leaflet

I'm trying to send the result of `HttpClient` `post` requests multiple components in my Angular app. I'm using a `Subject` and calling its `next()` method whenever a new `post` request is successfully executed. Each component subscribes to the service's `Subject`.

The faulty services is defined as

```js
@Injectable()
export class BuildingDataService {

  public response: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();

  constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchBuildingData(location) {
    ...

    this.http.post(url, location, httpOptions).subscribe(resp => {
      this.response.next(resp);
    });
}
```

The components subscribe to `BuildingService.response` as follows

```js
@Component({
  template: "<h1>{{buildingName}}</h1>"
  ...
})

export class SidepanelComponent implements OnInit {
  buildingName: string;

  constructor(private buildingDataService: BuildingDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildingDataService.response.subscribe(resp => {
        this.buildingName = resp['buildingName'];
      });
  }

  updateBuildingInfo(location) {
    this.buildingDataService.fetchBuildingData(location);
  }
}
```

`updateBuildingInfo` is triggered by users clicking on a map.

Retrieving the data from the server and passing it to the components works: I can output the payloads to the console in each component. However, the components' templates fail to update.

After Googling and fiddling for most of today I found that this implementation does not trigger Angular's change detection. The fix is to either

- wrap my call to `next()` in the service in `NgZone.run(() => { this.response.next(resp); }`
- call `ApplicationRef.tick()` after `this.title = resp['title']` in the component.

Both solutions feel like dirty hacks for such a trivial use case. There must be a better way to achieve this.

My question therefore is: what is the proper way to fetch data once and send it off to several components?

I'd furthermore like to understand why my implementation escapes Angular's change detection system.

**EDIT** it turns out I was initiating my call to `HttpClient` outside of Angular's zone hence it could not detect my changes, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to get an `Observable` of the `Subject` and use it in your template using `async` pipe:

```
(building | async)?.buildingName
```

Also, if different components are subscribing to the service at different times, you may have to use `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `Subject`.

---

```
@Injectable()
export class BuildingDataService {
  private responseSource = new Subject<object>();
  public response = this.responseSource.asObservable()

  constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchBuildingData(location) {
    this.http.post(url, location, httpOptions).subscribe(resp => {
      this.responseSource.next(resp);
    });
  }
}
```

---

```
@Component({
  template: "<h1>{{(building | async)?.buildingName}}</h1>"
  ...
})

export class SidepanelComponent implements OnInit {
  building: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private buildingDataService: DataService) {
      this.building = this.buildingDataService.response;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  updateBuildingInfo(location) {
    this.buildingDataService.fetchBuildingData(location);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, the `async` pipe produces the same effect: it only works when I trigger a manual change detection preferably through NgZone or else it lags one tick i.e. it displays the previous value instead of the current.

I'll research BehaviourSubject, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also make sure you are unsubscribing the subscriptions made manually. I don't really see any need for manual change detection in this scenario.

Comment: Also, you are injecting `DataService` instead of `BuildingDataService` is that a typo?

Comment: That's a typo; fixed now. I'm reaching for manual change detection since  the template does not update upon arrival of a new value through the Subject (or BehaviourSubject for that matter, see my comments in DiabolicWord's answer.

Comment: I found the issue: I'm triggering `fetchBuildingData` from a callback outside of Angular's zone. Thanks a lot for the different approaches; they helped me zone in on the problem. Your remark that you "don't really see any need for manual change detection in this scenario" somehow reminded me to look at how I call `fetchBuildingData`.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it's the closest to the sought solution. There's a missing `this` in the fourth line of the first code block, though. Can you add it?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with your question. You should accept your own answer not to confuse future readers.

Comment: I was unsure what to do as the other answers directly address the question about multicasting whereas my solution fixes something completely unrelated. I'd hate someone to Google for multicasting and end up on a page describing how to fix something with Leaflet. Still unsure what to, so please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this in an angular app is a getter in the service class.

```
get data()
{
     return data;
}
```

Why are you trying to complicate matters? What are the benefits, and if there are benefits they will overcome the drawbacks?

Comment: I want to push data to component A which is retrieved due to an user interacting with component B. I don't see how that can be done through getters as I'd have to call them explicitly from component A, right?

Comment: No you do not call them directly on component A. You inject the same Singleton service in both. You start retrivi ng data by calling a method on the singleton (ferchBuildingData). This method save the data in a member of the singleton. The member of the singleton is shared across any component with a getter. This is standard practice in angular, you can see this in the hero tutorial in the official documentation. An other elegant way to solve this problem is to use the redux library for angular, so implementing a state management (I like this a lot).

Comment: Yes, you're right, this works like a charm. I wasn't aware of the fact that getters are bound to values! This is indeed much simpler than the Subject/Observable approach.

Comment: Can you point me to the docs where `get` is mentioned? I can't find it...

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the issue. I briefly mention that `fetchBuildingData` is triggered by users clicking on a map; that map is Leaflet as provided by the `ngx-leaflet` module. I bind to its `click` event as follows

```
map.on('click', (event: LeafletMouseEvent) => {
  this.buildingDataService.fetchBuildingData(event.latlng);
});
```

The callback is, I now realise, fired outside Angular's zone. Angular therefore fails to detect the change to `this.building`. The solution is to bring the callback in Angular's zone through NgZone as

```
map.on('click', (event: LeafletMouseEvent) => {
  ngZone.run(() => {
    this.buildingDataService.fetchBuildingData(event.latlng);
  });
});
```

This solves the problem and every proposed solution works like a charm.

A big thank you for the quick and useful responses. They were instrumental in helping me narrow down the problem!

To be fair: this issue is mentioned in `ngx-leaflet`'s documentation [1]. I failed to understand the implications right away as I'm still learning Angular and there is a lot to take in.

[1] https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#a-note-about-change-detection

Comment: I was unsure what to do as the other answers directly address the question about multicasting whereas my solution fixes something completely unrelated. I'd hate someone to Google for multicasting and end up on a page describing how to fix something with Leaflet. Still unsure what to, so please advise.

Comment: Well, I think that makes sense too. I guess you can leave this as is.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As your change detection seems to struggle with whatsoever detail in your object, I have another suggestion. And as I also prefer the BehaviorSubject over a sipmple Subject I adjusted even this part of code.

**1st** define a wrapper object. The interesting part is, that we add a second value which definitely has to be unique compared to any other wrapper of the same kind you produce.

I usually put those classes in a models.ts which I then import wherever I use this model.

```
export class Wrapper {
   constructor(
       public object: Object,
       public uniqueToken: number
   ){}
}
```

**2nd** in your service use this wrapper as follows.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'; 
import { Wrapper } from './models.ts';

@Injectable()
export class BuildingDataService {
   private response: BehaviorSubject<Wrapper> = new BehaviorSubject<Wrapper>(new Wrapper(null, 0));

   constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

   public getResponse(): Observable<Wrapper> {
        return this.response.asObservable();
   }

   fetchBuildingData(location) {
      ...
      this.http.post(url, location, httpOptions).subscribe(resp => {

         // generate and fill the wrapper
         token: number = (new Date()).getTime();
         wrapper: Wrapper = new Wrapper(resp, token);

         // provide the wrapper
         this.response.next(wrapper);
      });
   }
```

Import the model.ts in all subscribing classes in order to be able to handle it properly and easily.  Let your Subscribers subscribe to the getResponse()-method.

This must work. Using this wrapper + unique token technique I always solved such change detection problems eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The problem, unfortunately, persists.

Comment: Hi, I understand. I updated my post. I hope this eventually works for you.

Comment: Thanks for this creative solution! Unfortunately it does not work either. I get the `BehaviourSubject`'s initial value but nothing afterwards _unless_ I wrap it in `NgZone.run()`. Seeing that your solution is very similar to @sabithpocker's I'm starting to think there is something wrong with my Angular installation (5.2.10). Alternatively, Angular does not do change detection in callbacks: I tried calling `next()` in the service every second through `setInterval` but it also only works by manually triggering a change detection.

Comment: I found the issue: I'm triggering `fetchBuildingData` from a callback outside of Angular's zone. See my solution. Thanks a million for the help! By providing a number of different solutions you helped me verify that the Subject/Observable part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code of sabith is wrong (but the idea is the correct)

```
  //declare a source as Subject
  private responseSource = new Subject<any>(); //<--change object by any

  public response = this.responseSource.asObservable() //<--use"this"

  constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchBuildingData(location) {
    this.http.post(url, location, httpOptions).subscribe(resp => {
      this.responseSource.next(resp);
    });
  }
```

Must be work

Another idea is simply using a getter in your component

```
//In your service you make a variable "data"
data:any
fetchBuildingData(location) {
    this.http.post(url, location, httpOptions).subscribe(resp => {
      this.data=resp
    });
  }

//in yours components

get data()
{
     return BuildingDataService.data
}
```

Comment: Yes, the getter works beautifully. I wasn't aware tha they are _bound_ to variables and automatically receive new values.

Comment: No it isn't exactly this way. Angular is not magic, it's must take acount the changes in the application (a click, a change in one input...). When a change happens, it look for all the "things" that can change and show the new values. Using a getter "force" to Angular to look for the new value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How does the "forcing" work? Is it something that's done in Angular or is it a property of JavaScript itself?

Comment: I don't know, but if you write console.log("***") into a getter you can see that is called several times. (perhaps "forcing" is not the correct word, sorry)